# GPU compute problems

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

i have a Intel Pentium is there ANY possible way to use it for GPU compute ? And can some one explain how GPU works and why my Intel is not compatible.

Comment: GPU Graphics Processing Unit typically means a dedicated video card.   CPU is not a GPU.  It is not the CPU Pentium Chip.  Perhaps a search on the video website that rhymes with noonoob  will explain in depth.  Please search for What is a GPU? and I feel certain you can see many videos there.  You probably should expect your question to be put on hold since it is not about the use of Blender.  Your question is a hardware question so it is teetering on the edge of ... off topic.  Please also consider asking your question on another Forum on Stack Exchange.  You will need to search for  that.

Comment: can you give me a link to a place were i can get more info

Comment: Literally just Google it lol but basically, a GPU is a special part of computers that not all have. Laptops often don't have them.

Comment: thank, but i am just trying to get some info!

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!!! i finely have it working YES!!